# How to understand page has been seen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

When the user enters the application,I am navigate the user to a intropage. But  if user has seen the intro page before, I do not want to show it again. (So I dont want to user see this page every time enter the application)

So how do I know if the user has seen the page? what way should i go?

Comment: keep track of it and store `isIntroSeen` in shared preferences.

Comment: Is there any understandable example that you can share for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using using the **sharedpreferences** package. here's the [link](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) for the package.

Here is a medium article for you to understand how to use the shared preferences
[Using SharedPreferences in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127)

Comment: Is there a code sample? So how can I tell when the user sees the page, I don't understand that part

Comment: It's extremely simple to do so. take a boolean and set it to false initially. when user is done with the intro slides, user can click on Done button which will trigger the boolean value and set it to true. Everytime the app gets opened check if the boolean value is false or true and you can redirect the users according to that.